# Is there any API for Google Plus Page Collections and Communities?

Tags: google-api, google-plus

I have read Google developers documents and have not yet find any API which is used to get Google Plus Pages Collections and Communities posts.Are the APIs available currently?

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no API for Google+ Pages or Communities.  The Google+ API is currently only for access to users data and is also sadly read-only.